# Doing search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I prepare query object and do search in elasticsearch.

For making query object, I give key and their value.

Problem is, when key and value is like "brand":"Men's Wear" then In this case elasticsearch is unable to give me related docs. I think problem is with comma or may be space. everything is fine if I use other json property for key and value (having no space and comma like "priority":"high")

Any help please!

Update:

no match query still not working! one more problem i found in creating search query. query i am using is:

```
var qryObj1 = {
                       "query" : {
                        "text" : {"name":"Tom"}
                    }
                };
```

This will return all docs having name Tom. Now I want to get all docs having name Tom and profession is developer. So, here modified one:

```
qryObj1 = {
                    "query" : {
                        "text" : {"name":"Tom","profession":"developer"}
                    },"operator" : "and"

                };
```

but search result is old one. any help!

Comment: I guess you need to provide your mapping, if you have submitted one, and the query that you're using to retrieve data from elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using TermQuery, aren't you?

TermQuery are not analyzed so they don't match with your analyzed content.

Try with a [MatchQuery](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html). It should work.

Comment: So, as @javanna wrote before, you should post more details (mapping, doc sent, query)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use boolean query
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html

Here you can ask ES to take AND or OR of various queries

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : [
                    "text" : {"name":"Tom"},
                    "text" : {"profession":"developer"}
    ]
```

}